# Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns 0-0 [#] in expression [#]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got this error when I click in this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-grey pull-right" data-ng-disabled="routeDesc.$invalid || !allowToContinue" data-ng-click="setupConstraints()">Próximo <span class="fa fa-spinner loader" loading></span></button>
        </div>
```

Complete error:

`Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [#] in expression [#].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.29/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%23%5D&p2=%23
    at VALIDITY_STATE_PROPERTY (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12)
    at Lexer.throwError (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:10411:11)
    at Lexer.lex (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:10365:16)
    at Parser.parse (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:10589:30)
    at fullExp.$get (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11447:37)
    at Object.ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).$rootScope.compile (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:19270:20)
    at applyDirectivesToNode (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6530:32)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6093:15)
    at compileNodes (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6105:15)
    at compile (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6026:15)`

Change `ng-click` for `ng-href` doesn't work for me and I have no idea what is this.

**EDIT:**

```
$scope.setupConstraints = function(){
        NewRouting.setName($scope.routing.name);
        var depot = Depots.get({
                depotId: $scope.routing.depot
            }, function(depot){
                var vehicles = Vehicles.query(function(){
                        NewRouting.setVehicles(vehicles);
                        NewRouting.setDepots([depot]);
                        $location.path('routings/create/5');
                    });
            });
    };
```

Comment: What does `setupConstraints()` do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills edited with setupConstraints() function.

Comment: Did you get a fix for this? what was the issue? I also get the similar error on calling apis from Angular..